# note: expected ‘float (*)[100]’ but argument is of type ‘float (*)[100][100]’

Tags: c, types, floating-point, arguments

I have warning:

```
note: expected ‘float (*)[100]’ but argument is of type ‘float (*)[100][100]’
```

My function looks like:

```
int readfile (float macierz_A[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], float macierz_B[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE])
...
float A[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];
float B[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];
int r1;// = 3;
r1 = readfile(&A, &B);
```

Any idea?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html , especially sections 12 and 18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
r1 = readfile(&A, &B);
```

Into this:

```
r1 = readfile(A, B);
```

Note that the & has been removed. Speaking in a very simple manner, you are passing a pointer to a multidimensional array, instead of the multidimensional array. (as you declared in the function declaration)

Answer (score 3):

```
void f(int p[M][N]);
```

is equivalent to

```
void f(int (*p) [N]); //pointer to array of N elements
```

In your case N is 100 and the compiler expects expression of type `int(*)[100]`. But since A is (presumably) of type `int[100][100]` then `&A` is of type `int(*)[100][100]` which is what the error tells you. You must pass A, not its addess, i.e.

```
readfile(A, B)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one level of indirection too much

```
r1 = readfile(&A, &B);
```

Just try

```
r1 = readfile(A, B);
```

---

Or, if you actually **want** a pointer to each matrix, change the function into

```
int readfile (float (*macierz_A)[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], float (*macierz_B)[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE])
```

Comment: It's not an extra level of indirection. It's merely a pointer to the same address but with the wrong type (pointer to a two-dimensional array instead of pointer to the first row of a two-dimensional array, which is itself a one-dimensional array).

Comment: @R.. - Well, yeah. I probably thought of the matrix and its rows as different levels, but that depends on how it is declared.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The problem here is that you are passing the **address** of A and B, both of which are 2 dimensional arrays, but in the function "readfile" you are only accepting values of float[100][100].

The reason that this is a warning and not an error is because: float [][] is also interpreted as float *[] by the compiler (just like int * is equivalent to int [] ).